# What is the use case of Power BI Report Builder, Report Builder, Power BI Desktop, Power BI Desktop (RS)?

Tags: powerbi

There seem to be 3 tools to create and publish Power BI reports.

1. Power BI Report Builder
2. Report Builder
3. Power BI Desktop
4. Power BI Desktop (RS)

What is the use case of these 4 different tools? Is one the subset of the other? Does one support more features than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Power BI Report Builder is a tool for authoring paginated reports that you can publish to the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder-power-bi).
2. Report builder is a standalone tool to design reports for [SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-deploy-and-manage-mobile-and-paginated-reports?view=sql-server-ver15).
3. [Power BI Desktop](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/) is used to build Power BI reports, which you can publish to Power BI Service.
4. [Power BI Desktop for Power BI Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/install-powerbi-desktop) is used to build Power BI reports, which you can publish to Power BI Report Server.

No, they are not subsets. You can say that Power BI Report Server is a superset, or successor of SSRS, which along with SSRS (.rdl) reports can render Power BI reports (.pbix) too.

Comment: What is the point of 1 over 3? 1 seems to be a lesser version of 3

Comment: @johnstaveley 1 is for .RDL, 3 is for .PBIX reports.

Comment: Any why would I want one over the other? Both seem to have the same objective of publishing to power bi service?

Comment: .RDL are pixel perfect reports, suitable for printing on paper, and having a completely different set of features. .pbix are interactive, designed to be used on a computer or mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

1.Power BI report builder is for paginated reports .

2.Report builder is the old SSRS. It is used to create static reports .
I find it outdated compared to Power BI desktop. Also it is hard to find videos /tutorials if you are new. Moreover if you are going to use large datasets, you will realise that it is slow.

3.Power BI desktop is used to build real time reports which you can publish/share to Power BI service.

4.Power BI for Power BI report Server is used to build your reports and publish them to Power BI report Server.